# determine character code in LaTeX3 (equivalent for backtick notation)

Tags: expl3

Is there some dedicated `expl3` command that is equivalent to the backtick notation of TeX in order to determine the character code?

Comment: The backtick notation is part of the 'core' TeX idea of a 'number': we've not tried to change that (not I think possible anyway). Is there some reason you can't use just a backtick in the normal way?

Comment: @JosephWright: I just asked out of curiosity. Of course, there is nothing more compact than a single backtick, and I am happy to use it without breaking l3 conventions. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As `expl3` is based on TeX primitives, ultimately it is constrained by the same rules as TeX (or at least e-TeX). In particular, the concept of a `<integer denotation>` which can be used inside an `<integer expression>` is the same in `expl3` as it is anywhere else in TeX (and `<integer expression>` is an e-TeX concept using the `\numexpr` primitive). The backtick notation is part of the standard TeX syntax for an `<integer denotation>` and so it forms part of the `expl3`  syntax too, such that

```
\int_eval:n { `a } % => 97
```

is perfectly valid. Almost all integer input for `expl3` takes the form of `<integer expression>`s, so something like

```
\int_eval:n { `z - ( `a - 1 ) } % => 26
```

is also valid.

At the moment, the documentation does not cover this sort of thing, but clearly we do need to address that.

Comment: It could be disabled by giving the backtick a different category code, but why would anybody want it? `;-)`

Comment: @egreg ``\the\catcode`\`\bye`` produces 12. I expected 13 (active character). Thus, it is impossible to define (or `\let`) a (L3) command that could be equivalent to a single backtick?

Comment: @AlexG The usual category code of the backtick is indeed 12; Plain TeX and LaTeX have `\lq` that is defined by ``\def\lq{`}`` so that `\lq` can be used in contexts of numbers: `\the\catcode\lq a` returns 11.

Comment: @Joseph : Is `\int_eval:n{ \`a }` to be preferred over `\number\`a` ?

Comment: @AlexG In `expl3` code certainly yes: we don't have a direct interface for the 'raw' `\number`: `\int_eval:n` is equivalent to `\number\numexpr#1\relax`.